# Solving circular dependencies with RouterModule

Tags: angular

I am boostrapping an Angular application. I am trying to follow the [official styleguide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide). More specifically, I need to understand how modules work.

Let's take this simple site map :

```
├── Home page
├── Profile page
│   ├── Preferences
│   ├── Change password
```

I want to structure the app with a "Core" module, a "Shared" module and a "Routing" module and 1 module for each part of the application ("Home" and "Profile" in this example) as follows :

```
├── CoreModule
├── SharedModule
├── RoutingModule
├── HomeModule
│   ├── Home Component
├── ProfileModule
│   ├── ProfileComponent
│   ├── PreferencesComponent
│   ├── ChangePasswordComponent
```

**Problem** :

1. `RoutingModule` needs to know about `ProfileComponent`. So `RoutingModule` imports `ProfileModule`.
2. In `ProfileComponent`, I need some `<a [routerLink]="...">` in order to enable navigation to sub components. So `ProfileModule` needs to import `RoutingModule`.

Hence, **I get a circular dependency**. How do I solve this circular dependency?

**EDIT** : for future googlers, there is a [good example](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules) in the `NgModules` part of the official documentation.

Comment: Why don't you import both `RoutingModule` and `ProfileModule` into `AppModule`? Here they get to know about each other.

Comment: In the routing module you can import ProfileComponent directly from it's source file. You don't need to import ProfileModule for that. I may be wrong, but you can atleast try?

Comment: @DiabolicWords if I get it right, all modules declared in AppModule will be eagerly 
 loaded. I would like to avoid that and load modules when the user accesses it for the first time.

Comment: @VinodBhavnani I tried that but I get this error message : `Component ProfileComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't have to import your `AppRoutingModule` to use `<a [routerLink]="...">`.  To use `<a [routerLink]="...">` you only need to import `RouterModule` in your `app.module.ts` file.

So your `app.module.ts` should look something like:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppRouterModule } from './app-router.module';

// Other imports including ProfileComponent

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // various including ProfileComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Your `app-router.module.ts` should look something like:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ProfileComponent } from '..';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'profile-component-url',
    component: ProfileComponent
  },
  // Other routes
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRouterModule { }
```

Then anywhere you want to add a router link to `ProfileComponent` simply use this in your HTML:

```
<a routerLink='/profile-component-url'>
```

Hence there is no circular dependancy as  your `RouterModule` relies on `ProfileComponent` but not the other way round.

If you want to benefit from Lazy loading you will need another router module, which will be use `RouterModule.forChild(routes)` instead of `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)` which references all the Components etc from the Lazy loaded module, and you will need to reference it in your main router module as follows:

```
  {
    path: 'some-path',
    loadChildren: './modules/..path-to-other-module../lazy-loaded.module#LazyLoadedModule'
  },
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation about the 2nd router module. I was wondering about that too :)

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle To use lazy loading you should remove all references to the components which are to be lazy loaded from the main module and only include them in the lazy-loaded module.  Otherwise they will not be lazy loaded

Comment: That is actually very useful to know when using SCAM (single component angular module) pattern.